# When is the best time to change gear?

Tags: motor-world-car-factory

I lose all my races because I don't know when to change. I have tried at the start of the darkest red bit but I still seem to lose.

Answer (score 2):

Change gear as soon as the number of the gear starts flashing, keep your finger ready, don't change before that because that will make the car slower. That worked for me.